# Laravel share variable to views in custom middleware group

Tags: php, laravel, view, composer-php

I need to put $page variable into views in some group of routes. I found one solution to put routes in middleware group and in middleware use `View::share`. But if I place any function in middleware will this code run for 
How does view composer work? Does it try to run function on each view? I'm just thinking about performance if one page is from multiple views....

**Middleware:**

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
     View::share('page', Page::get());

     return $next($request);
}
```

Will query for getting `Pages` get called once for multiple views?

Comment: Could you please share some code that will help to understand your question more clear?

Comment: @sachinkumar updated my question

Comment: Any middleware will get executed only once per request, so if you run a query in a middleware it will be executed only once in this case. If you want you can add a `\Log::info('shared page to view');` line for example and see how many times the message will be logged in the `laravel.log` file.

Comment: I understand that middleware runs once per request. I just wasn't sure if view which has included other views will not run this code multiple times...

Comment: If you are worried about performance then you can go with View::composer where you can define the list of views to attach composer view with them. And as we know once a view is rendering it will be cached by laravel.

Comment: As Bogdan said, middleware runs "once per request". When a view includes another view, that is done in a request, after the middleware has already run, so you don't have to worry about it getting called multiple times.

Comment: You're invoking the `Page::get()` method before the `share` method is executed. If you were to write your code like this `$page = Page::get(); View::share('page', $page);` it would be even more obvious that you're passing the value returned by a function call, that is only executed once before the data "sharing" occurs. In short the middleware is getting the data from the database, not the View facade, and the middleware is run once, so you should not be concerned about performance issues.

Comment: @general666 use viewComposer instead of frankensteining a middleware. https://laravel.com/docs/master/views#view-composers

Comment: @sachinkumar By default the Blade views are compiled by Laravel to PHP, but the data passed to them is not, so the query will run once on each request. Don't mistake the view cache with the data cache.

Comment: @N69S using `View::share` in a middleware, instead of using `View::composer` for sharing generic data such as the current page, can be actually more maintainable when you need it applied to a lot of routes that use a lot of views, instead of adding a lot of view names to the composer definition which needs to be updated each time a new view is added.

Comment: @N69S exactly as Bogdan mentioned. I need to use it on multiple routes. This is the best workaround I found. Now I can just use middleware group for routes where I need and everything works as expected. Thank you everybody

Comment: @Bogdan  the issue is not abour the method `share`, the issue is that you're using middleware to do a controller/view work wich is not maintainable in the long run. middlewares are for session control.I gave the link to encourge you to check the `ViewServiceProvider` format.

Comment: @N69S I'm sorry but the **"middleware are for session control"** statement is just wrong. If you check the actual [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/master/middleware#introduction) you'll see that it exemplifies uses for middleware from adding CORS headers to responses, to logging data. And I argue that in this case writing code that doesn't require change to work for any future defined routes and views is *more* maintainable. I'm not saying that using composers wouldn't be a correct use case, but sometimes workarounds can be useful, even if they detract from the purity of the approach.